# How to shift PDF page using perl (CAM::PDF, PDF::API2)?

Tags: perl, pdf, ghostscript

I have a PDF document which I need to shift the pages to the right several inches. I.e like putting a margin on the left hand side of the page.

Can either CAM::PDF or PDF::API2 do it?
Or is there anyone have experience with it?

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done using ghostscript by setting up the Margins and HWMargin, but I want to do it in Perl instead of invoking external command via system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/).  The following little program shifts the page contents right by 100 points.

```
use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('my.pdf');
my $page = $pdf->getPage(1);
$page->{MediaBox}->{value}->[0]->{value} -= 100;
$page->{MediaBox}->{value}->[2]->{value} -= 100;
$pdf->cleanoutput('out.pdf');
```

I used "use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($page);" to remind myself of the $page data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it in PDF::API2:

```
use PDF::API2;

my $in  = PDF::API2->open('/path/to/file.pdf');
my $out = PDF::API2->new();

# Choose your margin (72 = one inch)
my $x_offset = 72;
my $y_offset = 0;

foreach my $page_num (1 .. $in->pages()) {
    # Take the source page and import it as an XObject
    my $xobject = $out->importPageIntoForm($in, $page_num);

    # Add the XObject to the new PDF
    my $page = $out->page();
    my $gfx = $page->gfx();
    $gfx->formimage($xobject, $x_offset, $y_offset);
}
$out->saveas('/path/to/new.pdf');
```

Another way that should work is to adjust the coordinates for the mediabox (and possibly other boxes):

```
use PDF::API2;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->open('/path/to/file.pdf');

# Choose your margin (72 = one inch)
my $x_offset = 72;
my $y_offset = 0;

foreach my $page_num (1 .. $pdf->pages()) {
    my $page = $pdf->openpage($page_num);

    # Get the coordinates for the page corners
    my ($llx, $lly, $urx, $ury) = $page->get_mediabox();

    # Add the margin by shifting the mediabox in the opposite direction
    $llx -= $x_offset;
    $lly -= $y_offset;
    $urx -= $x_offset;
    $ury -= $y_offset;

    # Store the new coordinates for the page corners
    $page->mediabox($llx, $lly, $urx, $ury);
}

$pdf->saveas('/path/to/new.pdf');
```

If you run into issues with content getting cut off, you may need to get and set one or more of `cropbox`, `bleedbox`, `trimbox`, and `artbox` as well, but this should work in most cases.

Comment: I've always thought that PDF::API2 has a nicer API than my own module, CAM::PDF. If I had gobs of free time, I'd like to merge them into single super PDF library...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that also with [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/). I'll give you some example commands for Windows (when using Unix, just replace `gswin32c.exe` by `gs`):

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o input-shifted-pages-1-inch-to-left.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -c "<</PageOffset [-72 0]>> setpagedevice" ^
   -f /path/to/input.pdf
```

1. `-o` : specifies the output file. Implicitly also uses `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER`.
2. `-sDEVICE=...` : asks Ghostscript to output PDF.
3. `-c <<...` : a PostScript code snippet passed on the commandline to make happen the page shift
4. `-f ...` : specifies the input PDF (`-f` is required after using `-c`).

The units used by `/PageShift` are PostScript points. 72 pt == 1 inch. The value `[-72 0]` shifts 72pt==1in to the left and 0in to top/bottom. Now you know how to shift 2 inches to the right:

```
gswin32c ^
   -o input-shifted-pages-2-inches-to-right.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -c "<</PageOffset [144 0]>> setpagedevice" ^
   -f /path/to/input.pdf
```

Wanna shift 0.5 in to the bottom and 1 inch to the right?

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o input-shifted-pages-1-inch-to-right-half-inch-down.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
   -c "<</PageOffset [72 -36]>> setpagedevice" ^
   -f /path/to/input.pdf
```